# how to perform a selective ST_Split?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to cut different lines with an identical geometry but different attributes (eg. colour) with a set of points. The points also have the attribute colour.
My knife points should only cut the lines with the same colour value. Red points should cut only red lines, green points should only cut green lines and so on...
I tried the following:

```
with knife as(
    select st_union(geom) as geom, colour
    from points
    group by colour)
select lines.colour,(st_dump(st_split(lines.geom,knife.geom))).geom as geom
from lines, knife
where lines.colour=knife.colour
```

Sadly, my 'selective knife' isn't so selective and cuts all lines regardless of their colour.
Can anybody help?

Edit: 
@JimJones I couldn't find a SQL-fiddle that supports the PostGIS extension. But with my data sample the knife somehow works perfectly. 
I have no idea why whats wrong with my real data. The real data lines are in fact multilinestrings, could that be a problem? (I somehow struggling in creating multilinestrings with the insert-statement) 
Edit2: 
found a fiddle with PostGIS
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8642640bb690dfee7d31006a673e2dcf)*

```
create table points(
id serial,
colour varchar,
geom geometry(point,4326)
);

create table lines(
id serial,
colour varchar,
geom geometry(linestring,4326)
);

insert into lines(colour, geom)
VALUES
('red','linestring(1 1,10 1)'),
('green','linestring(1 1,10 1)'),
('blue','linestring(1 1,10 1)');

insert into points(colour, geom)
VALUES
('red',(st_makepoint(2,1))),
('red',(st_makepoint(4,1))), 
('red',(st_makepoint(6,1))), 
('red',(st_makepoint(8,1))), 
('green',(st_makepoint(2.5,1))), 
('green',(st_makepoint(5,1))),
('green',(st_makepoint(7.5,1))),
('blue',(st_makepoint(3,1))),
('blue',(st_makepoint(6,1))),
('blue',(st_makepoint(9,1)));

with knife as(
    select st_union(geom) as geom, colour
    from points
    group by colour)
select lines.colour,(st_dump(st_split(lines.geom,knife.geom))).geom as geom
from lines, knife
where lines.colour=knife.colour
´´´


  [1]: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8642640bb690dfee7d31006a673e2dcf
```

Comment: Could you provide a data sample and the exact expected result? Preferably add create table and insert statements in a fiddle.

Comment: Hi! +1 for the fiddle :) I'm having a hard time trying to understand what could be wrong in your query.. it looks just fine. MultiLinestrings aren't an issue for ST_Split (according to documentation). Perhaps it is due the fact that this function always return a collection, and since your geometry is a multilinestring, it might be resulting in a collection of linestrings after the cut.

Comment: I think I understand my problem now. It's the way my lines became multilinestrings in the first place. I used to have a lot of small lines so I used ST_Union on them (or ST_Collect). Somehow Postgis still remembers, that theese lines where seperated once and when the st_dump occours, they become serated again. If I use the default 'dissolve'-tool in QGIS und upload the layer into the DB, the knife works just fine. Which brings up a new question: Is there a function in PostGIS that is equivalent to 'Dissolve' in QGIS? Switching to QGIS for this operation would slow me heavily...

Comment: I guess ST_Dump is the only way to do this. Would be an option for you to re-group the linestrigns again after the cut?

Comment: the ST_Dump seems not the problem, its the way I merge the lines that gives me headaches. Using ST_Dump with the knife after the Qgis Dissolve ist fine. Are there any other functions like ST_Union or ST_Collect?

Comment: I see. Have you alerady checked `ST_UnaryUnion()`? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=40e47d7ebbbfb801d940380bcd72723c

Comment: I have now...  ...no improvement. But I tried to squeeze an ST_Linemerge in front of the ST_Split and surprisingly it seems to do the trick. I still have to validate this on monday, but at least I get the same results like with QGIS Dissolve. So the Dump looks like that now: (St_Dump(St_Split(ST_Linemerge(lines.geom),knife.geom))).geom

Comment: Sounds promising! Don't forget to report it here on Monday.. such a research must be well documented  ;) have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Im a postgres beginner. Even though I'm quite sure that I found the solution to my problem, there could be something wrong. So feel free to correct me if necessary* 
If you want to ST_Split a line, which you formerly merged by using ST_Union, you sould use ST_Linemerge before the ST_Split and ST_Dump.
Even after a ST_Union, PostGIS seems to 'remember' that theese lines were formerly playing for different teams. So when you ST_Slit with you new knife and ST_Dump the GeometryCollection, the linestring is cut at the 'old soldering points' as well.
If you ST_Linemerge after the ST_Union, PostGIS seems to iron out theese connection points and you can safely use your knife.

In this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b751b192094ad0d30b17f28e016e966), I created 2 linetypes and some knife points. There is one solid line (blue) and some yellow line segments which are partly overlapping but all together have the same spatial extent as the blue line.
I used ST_Union and ST_Collect respectively (grouped by colour) to merge the yellow line segments into one single line (with no effect on the blue line, obviously).
In a second step I splitted and dumped the lines again with my knife points, one time with st_linemerge and one time without st_linemerge for the 'unioned' und 'collected' lines respectively.
The results (I counted the number of new segments and the cummulated line length for each colour) show, that only the split after the linemerged st_union gives the correct result. Using only St_Union results in the right length, but the number of linesegments is wrong. ST_Collect will keep the formerly overlapping parts,so the length as well as the number of segments are not usefull at all(for my purpose).